# JTable do not refresh

Tags: java, swing, jtable, refresh

I have a problem with a jTable, it doesn't refresh the data automatically but only when i move a border of the window or i click on cells.

```
public class DataTab extends TableModel {
  public DataTab(String[][] data) {

          this.data = data;
  }

  .....
  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
              data[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (String) aValue;
              fireTableUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);

  }

  public void fireTableUpadate(int rowIndex, int columnIndex){
              data= generateRandomMatrix();
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, are you firing the relevant events to the listeners? Extending `AbstractTableModel` instead of `TableModel` may help here (as well as tests).

Comment: the new matrix is generated when i edit any cell of the table

Comment: It doesn't look like you are firing events at any point.

Comment: Yes the code is not correct, DataTab exetends AbstractTableModel, but how can i go on from here?

Comment: It's difficult to tell when the code is not correct! You should probably be calling `AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated`, but not overriding it (or overriding it, and calling the `super` method). Also, I suggest testing.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).